# how to read environment variables set by jenkins in react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, environment-variables, dotenv

I am using custom webpack configuration with dotenv and setting env variables using jenkins and docker. The problem is when I console.log **process.env** in react app.js it is giving me undefined.

This is the part of webpack config for dotenv.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config().parsed)
})
```